# Prove pointwise convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Prove that $$f_n(t) = \frac{n^2t}{e^{nt}}$$ is pointwise convergent to the function $$f(t)=0$$ on interval $[0,1]$

Comment: I think this limit will be equal to 0, but I can't prove it formally. Maybe there is some inequality, but I have no idea.

Comment: Hint: L'Hôpital or $e^{nt}=1+nt+\frac12n^2t^2+\frac16n^3t^3+\cdots\ge1+\frac16n^3t^3$.

Comment: Please don't just dump your homework problems on MSE.

Comment: Rule of thumb: any exponential of n is stronger than any power of n, and n faculty beats both.

Answer (score 0):

If $t=0$, there's nothing to prove.

Otherwise, rewrite $f_n(t)$ as $\,\dfrac1t\,\dfrac{(nt)^2}{\mathrm e^{nt}}$.  Setting $nt=u$, we obtain $\;\dfrac1t\,\dfrac{u^2}{\mathrm e^u}$.Now it's a basic fact that $$\text{for all }t>0,\qquad\lim_{u\to +\infty}\dfrac{u^r}{\mathrm e^u}=0.$$